# Formulas should start at the same position

Tags: math-mode, positioning

I am a very beginner of LaTeX and I do not have any kind of experience with it.

How can I make formulas start at the same position such that they are aligned exactly underneath each other.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\underline{Verschiebare Ger{\"a}te}

\begin{equation*}    
P_j(t,s_j) = 
\begin{cases} 
 0 & \text{f"ur } t < s_j \ Q_j(t-s_j) & \text{f"ur } s_j \leq t \leq s_j + p_j \ 0 & \text{f"ur } t \textgreater s_j + p_j    
\end{cases}    
mit s_j = r_j + \Delta t \ \Delta t \leq tDoF    
\end{equation*}    
\end{document}
```

My problem refers to the last two formulars. I want the `\Delta t` to start exactly underneath the `s_j`, so the equality signs of those two formulars should start at the same position, but underneath each other.

Comment: Perhaps the documentclass option `fleqn` is what you are searching for?

Comment: Hi and welcome, instead of shooting into the blue, a bit of scientific preparation might be a good idea. If you want to know more about typesetting maths, please have a look at [Mathmode](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: You might be interested in TeXwelt.de, agerman site with the same Question and Anwer format and goLaTeX, a classical german discussion forum.

Comment: Remember to [accept one of the answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) if you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I've guessed what you want but here is a try:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % used to show page width
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
P_{j}(t, s_{j}) =
\begin{cases}
0                & \text{f{\"u}r $t < s_{j}$,}\\
Q_{j}(t - s_{j}) & \text{f{\"u}r $s_{j} \leq t \leq s_{j} + p_{j}$,}\\
0                & \text{f{\"u}r $t > s_{j} + p_{j}$,}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
mit $s_{j} = r_{j} + \Delta t$ f{\"u}r $\Delta t \leq tDoF$.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `align` environment to align math at specific parts:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P_j(t,s_j) &= \begin{cases}
    0 &  \text{f"ur  } t < s_j   \\
        Q_j(t-s_j) & \text{f"ur  } s_j  \leq t \leq  s_j  + p_j  \\
        0 & \text{f"ur  } t \textgreater s_j + p_j
   \end{cases}\\
%\intertext{mit}\\
\text{mit }&s_j = r_j +  \Delta t  \\
&\Delta t \leq tDoF
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

To add text on it's own line you can use `intertext` or if you want it inline use `text` as you already did.

[image]

Or if you want the equation symbols directly underneath each other:

```
\text{mit }s_j &= r_j +  \Delta t  \\
\Delta t &\leq tDoF
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `align`environment. Be careful to use `\\` to break lines.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools} 

\begin{document}

\underline{Verschiebare Ger{\"a}te}
\begin{align*}
P_j(t,s_j) &= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{f"ur } t < s_j \\
   Q_j(t-s_j) & \text{f"ur } s_j \leq t \leq s_j + p_j \\
   0 & \text{f"ur } t \textgreater s_j + p_j \end{cases} \\
\text{mit } s_j& = r_j + \Delta t \ \Delta t \leq tDoF
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```